# Textblock not aligned as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, triggers, styles

So this is part of my UI right now:

At the top I got a `CheckBox` boud to `bool ShowChangeColumn`.

**What I want is that when there is no `ParentSubject` which is displayed in Row 5 (`Index 4`) that the `Subject` of ticket is centered vertically.**

[image]

Sadly what I did is not working. What is wrong here ?

> I am expecting the 2nd row to `Collapse` when there is no `Content`  - and the 1st row to fill all the available space - respecting the `VerticalAlignment="Center"` of that`TextBox` in the 1st row.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0" Height="35">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" Grid.Row="0" ToolTip="{Binding Subject}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentTicketSubject}" Grid.Row="1"> 
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.ShowChangeColumn}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ParentTicketSubject}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ParentTicketSubject}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: what if use * instead of Auto inside RowDefinition?

Comment: that does not change anything :/ I tried that before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer when setting the `Height="0"` for the second column.

**The text on the top was the same as before**

So what I came up with was:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

1. Fill all available space possible
2. If collapsed -> hide

Like this it was working as expected.

[image]

Comment: I am glade that you found the answer on your own :)

Comment: And I am feeling dumb somehow :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Auto will say, if there is nothing inside, my height will be 0px
if you put * on both rowdefinition, it will normaly use 50% for the first one and the 50% left will be used by the last one.

Comment: I want the 2nd row to collapse, so the the first one can fill all space...

Answer (score 0):

Try with.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.ShowChangeColumn}" Value="False">
 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />   
 <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
</DataTrigger>
```